# I can't find server.xml?

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat7, centos7, tomcat9

Need help on tracking or knowing where I can find the connection port of tomcat on my linux server.

i found that there are 2 tomcat version installed

1. Apache tomcat/9.0.13 with IP XXX.XXX.1.96:8889/manager/html
2. Apache tomcat/7.0.76 with same IP XXX.XXX.1.96:8081/manager/html

I already found server.xml path but its the 7.0.76 tomcat. I can't find the server.xml or anything with connection port 8889. I'm trying to add gzip on it. gzip is now present on 7.0.76 but not on 9.0.13.

anyone can help me?
also this was a server that was endorsed to me. I did not setup it. and now can't contact the last person to set this up. thanks!

already add gzip on etc/tomcat/server.xml but the changes was reflected on toncat 7 not the tomcat9